# Could not find stored procedure 'sql'

Tags: sql

I suddenly have begun to get the error message

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'sql'

when I run a query. The query still executes correctly, but the output has the message at the top.

No more than 10 minutes ago the queries worked fine (without the message), but now it gives this error. Is there a way to either fix the problem or suppress the error message in the query result?

Thank you

Comment: Please post the code being used to execute the query

Comment: Need to see some code, please. What language are u calling the sql from, etc. Need. More. Info.

Comment: @trev said "No more than 10 minutes ago the queries worked fine", have you been makeing changes in those 10 minutes, if so look at what you changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.  Can you check to see if this stored procedure executes stored procedures internally?  Perhaps there in a case statement in the stored procedure that sometimes calls a stored procedure that is missing.